# Stacked Bar chart not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/MErMvIgG9MOdXmjBPZVq?p=preview

I'm trying to create an example of a stacked bar chart, doing this in Angular. The example I have is a mix of different things from different examples. It's meant to be a horizontal chart with axis on the bottom and left.

Can anyone offer any advice on where I'm going wrong?

```
let layer = this.svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .style("fill", (d, i) => {
        return colorFn(i);
    });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data((d) => { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", (d) => { return this.yScale(this.parseDate(d.data.date)); })
    .attr("x", (d) => { return this.xScale(d[0]); })
    .attr("height", this.yScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", (d) => { return this.xScale(d[1]) - this.xScale(d[0]) });
```

Comment: Not sure what the final product is supposed to look like, but the axis problem is simple: you're calling xAxis twice and never provide a `.call(this.yAxis)`. Adding that will bring your y axis back. You're also appending your chart elements directly to the svg element rather than the translated `g` element causing them to overlap the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `date` key/value pair...

```
date: "2014"
```

... your specifier is incorrect. It should be:

```
d3.timeParse("%Y");
```

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/k8aZSlyCCtpWArOO0mki?p=preview

PS: You don't even need to parse the dates. Since your y scale uses a categorical variable, just use the dates as they are right now, that is, simple strings.

Comment: What the best way to turn the chart from horizontal to vertical. I now need the dates along the bottom x axis and the stacked chart to be vertical. I have tried swapping the xScale and yScale but that doesn't work - https://plnkr.co/edit/ggPXzhZFotS9oviaCafr?p=preview

Comment: It's not that simple. Also, as this is not related to your problem here, I suggest you post it as a new question.